# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute - although specified

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I am trying to get run application.yml instead of application.properties. But it fails. Please help. The same thing works in application.properties.

My **application.yml** looks like this:

```
spring:
    profiles: container
    jpa:
        show-sql: true
        database: MYSQL
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: update
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://mysql57:3308/hello_java
        username: demo_java
        password: 1234
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-04-03 10:40:26.671 ERROR 12600 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Try quote marks around jdbc:mysql://mysql57:3308/hello_java. Seems that `:` in the jdbc url is breaking the yaml parsing.

Comment: Show your config class.

Comment: @lainatnavi Any `:` after the first is seen as literal.